Remix Submit Object
What's the right way of submitting object in remix using useSubmit()?
Do i need to JSON.stringify() it first? Then JSON.parse() it in the action?
My code below is working but not sure if its the best way?
onSubmit()
const onSubmit = () => {

    const updatedContact = {
        name: "John Doe",
        email: "",
    };

    const updatedOrder = {
        products: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Product 1",
                quantity: 1,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Product 2",
                quantity: 2,
            },
        ],
        total: 100,
    };

    const product = JSON.stringify(updatedContact);
    const order = JSON.stringify({
        updatedOrder: updatedOrder,
    });

    const formData = {
        id,
        product,
        order,
    };

    submit(formData, { method: "post", encType: "multipart/form-data" });
};

action
export const action: ActionFunction = async ({
    request
}: ActionFunctionArgs) => {
    const formData = await request.formData();

    const {
        id,
        product,
        order,
    } = Object.fromEntries(formData) as {
        [k: string]: string;
    };

    console.log({
        id,
        product: JSON.parse(product),
        order: JSON.parse(order),
    })

};


no you dont need it. anyway if you want you can do it)

You can now use JSON directly instead of always using form data.
submit({ id, product, order }, { method: 'post', encType: 'appliction/json' })

function action({ request} ) {
  const { id, product, order } = await request.json()
  //...
}

https://remix.run/docs/en/main/hooks/use-submit#options

Do I still need to JSON.stringify() when submit? and JSON.parse() in the actions?

No, just pass in the object as the first argument to submit

Weird. Why am I getting this error? TypeError: Content-Type was not one of "multipart/form-data" or "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". I'm using @remix-run/cloudflare

Which version of Remix are you on? The application/json type was added in v1.18.0 https://github.com/remix-run/remix/releases/tag/remix%401.18.0

I'm using "@remix-run/cloudflare": "^2.9.1" and @remix-run/react": "^2.9.1". The error happens on the actions when I console.log it.

Ok, so how are you parsing the request body? Are you using request.json() or are you still using request.formData()?

I see. Thank you. So you’ll only need to change request.formData() if you decide to NOT use application/json?
